# Converting Check Amount To Words Using Case/Methods

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project for my Visual Basic class, which is to create a digital check. The assignment requires us to input a check amount, which translates into words. In example, $1,200.00 needs to output "One thousand two hundred dollars"

For the most part, my code works. I'm using a switch statement. The original assignment was to have our check go up to a 9,999 value, but as we continue to build, we need to be able to convert up to 99,999.

As I said, I've been using a series of case statements, but realize that this is a very "hard code" way of doing this and would like create a method that can check these type of things for me, however I'm still new to Visual Basic and don't really have a good idea where to start or what is applicable in this scenario (we don't really have an example to go by.)

Here is my WriteCheck method that does the assigning/converting for the most part.

> ```
>     'Convert check value from a text field to a double'
>     Try
>         checkValue = checkInput.Text
>     Catch ex As InvalidCastException
>         MessageBox.Show("You must enter a numbers to write a check.")
>     End Try
>
>     'Operation to convert number to String'
>
>     thousands = checkValue \ 1000
>     hundreds = checkValue Mod 1000
>     hundreds = hundreds \ 100
>     tens = checkValue Mod 100
>     tens = tens \ 10
>     ones = checkValue Mod 10
>     ones = ones \ 1
>
>     'Case for thousands'
>     Select Case thousands & hundreds & tens
>         Case 1
>             tempStringT = "One"
>         Case 2
>             tempStringT = "Two"
>         Case 3
>             tempStringT = "Three"
>         Case 4
>             tempStringT = "Four"
>         Case 5
>             tempStringT = "Five"
>         Case 6
>             tempStringT = "Six"
>         Case 7
>             tempStringT = "Seven"
>         Case 8
>             tempStringT = "Eight"
>         Case 9
>             tempStringT = "Nine"
>
>     End Select
>
>     'Case for hundreds'
>     Select Case hundreds
>         Case 1
>             tempStringH = "one"
>         Case 2
>             tempStringH = "two"
>         Case 3
>             tempStringH = "three"
>         Case 4
>             tempStringH = "four"
>         Case 5
>             tempStringH = "five"
>         Case 6
>             tempStringH = "six"
>         Case 7
>             tempStringH = "seven"
>         Case 8
>             tempStringH = "eight"
>         Case 9
>             tempStringH = "nine"
>
>     End Select
>
>     'Case for tens'
>     Select Case tens Or ones
>         Case 1
>             tempStringTens = "one"
>         Case 2
>             tempStringTens = "twenty"
>         Case 3
>             tempStringTens = "thirty"
>         Case 4
>             tempStringTens = "fourty"
>         Case 5
>             tempStringTens = "fifty"
>         Case 6
>             tempStringTens = "sixty"
>         Case 7
>             tempStringTens = "seventy"
>         Case 8
>             tempStringTens = "eighty"
>         Case 9
>             tempStringTens = "ninety"
>
>     End Select
>
>     If tempStringTens <> "one" Then
>         'Case for ones'
>         Select Case ones
>             Case 1
>                 tempStringO = "one"
>             Case 2
>                 tempStringO = "two"
>             Case 3
>                 tempStringO = "three"
>             Case 4
>                 tempStringO = "four"
>             Case 5
>                 tempStringO = "five"
>             Case 6
>                 tempStringO = "six"
>             Case 7
>                 tempStringO = "seven"
>             Case 8
>                 tempStringO = "eight"
>             Case 9
>                 tempStringO = "nine"
>
>         End Select
>
>         lblConverted.Text = tempStringT & " thousand " & tempStringH & " hundred " & tempStringTens & " " & tempStringO & " dollars " & change & "/100"
>
>     End If
>
>
>
>     If tempStringTens = "one" Then
>         Select Case ones
>             Case 1
>                 tempStringO = "eleven"
>             Case 2
>                 tempStringO = "twelve"
>             Case 3
>                 tempStringO = "thirteen"
>             Case 4
>                 tempStringO = "fourteen"
>             Case 5
>                 tempStringO = "fifteen"
>             Case 6
>                 tempStringO = "sixteen"
>             Case 7
>                 tempStringO = "seventeen"
>             Case 8
>                 tempStringO = "eighteen"
>             Case 9
>                 tempStringO = "nineteen"
>         End Select
>
>         lblConverted.Text = tempStringT & " thousand " & tempStringH & " hundred " & tempStringO & " dollars"
>
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Is this `VB` or `VBA`?  Obviously the question is generic to some degree, but you may want to tag as `VB` for the best expertise.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually having a hard time figuring out how to tag this so I just gave one a shot!

Comment: This question is offtopic because you are asking us to build the whole algorithm. You should try something by your own and reach an acceptable stage before asking here. As a quick hint, to reduce this kind of lots of hard-coding you have to locate common parts where only easily-automatisable bits are varying. For example, instead of doing `Dim val1 As String = "1000" If param = 2 Then val1 = "2000" ElseIf param = 3 Then Val1 = "3000", etc.` you might do: `Function calculateVal1(param As Integer) As String
    Return param.ToString() & "000"
End Function` and `val1 = calculateVal1(param)`.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but that is not what I am asking. I am asking for a starting point since I'm not receiving the information I need in the classroom.

I know to combine common parts, but I'm having trouble logically coming up with a solution that relates to my problem, since I have to break this problem into multiple pieces. A case seems appropriate here, but I do not know where to begin with turning a case into encompassing method for the problem that I have.

Comment: I have given you a starting point: find common parts (e.g., "Six" and "Sixteen" have "Six" in common) and rely (ideally recursively) on functions. Your `lblConverted.Text = tempStringT & " thousand "` can be converted into `lblConverted.Text = function1(ar1) & " " & function2(arg2)`. In any case, asking very basic things is also off-topic here. You should complement the lessons with work by your own + research. But only ask here once you've got a basic understanding and how to solve specific issues which cannot easily be found somewhere else (+ might be helpful to others).

Comment: Here's some VBA code http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/02/converting-numbers-to-words-part-v/ Maybe you can convert it to .Net and then if you have any problems with the conversion, post the question here.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to the problem. The solution can be easily scaled up or down by adding or removing items in `BigNumbers` and upping the scope of `num` beyond `Long` if necessary. (As written, it will work for numbers up to 999,999,999,999,999.)

```
Public Function NumberToText(ByVal num As Long) As String
    Dim BigNumbers() As String = {"", " Thousand", " Million", " Billion", " Trillion"}
    Dim TextParts() As String = {}
    If num < 0 Then
        Return "Checks cannot be written for negative amounts."
    ElseIf num >= 10 ^ ((BigNumbers.Length) * 3) Then
        Return "This number exceeds the current maximum value of " & NumberToText(10 ^ ((BigNumbers.Length) * 3) - 1) & "."
    End If
    Dim LoopCount As Integer = 0
    While num >= 1000
        ReDim Preserve TextParts(TextParts.Length)
        If num Mod 1000 > 0 Then
            TextParts(TextParts.GetUpperBound(0)) = ThreeDigitText(num Mod 1000) & BigNumbers(LoopCount)
        End If
        num = num \ 1000
        LoopCount += 1
    End While
    ReDim Preserve TextParts(TextParts.Length)
    TextParts(TextParts.GetUpperBound(0)) = ThreeDigitText(num) & BigNumbers(LoopCount)
    If Array.IndexOf(TextParts, "Error") > -1 Then
        Return "An unknown error occurred while converting this number to text."
    Else
        Array.Reverse(TextParts)
        Return Join(TextParts)
    End If
End Function

Private Function ThreeDigitText(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    If num > 999 Or num < 0 Then
        Return "Error"
    Else
        Dim h As Integer = num \ 100 'Hundreds place
        Dim tempText As String = ""
        If h > 0 Then
            tempText = OneDigitText(h) & " Hundred"
        End If
        num -= h * 100
        If num > 0 And Not tempText = "" Then
            tempText &= " "
        End If
        If num > 9 And num < 20 Then
            Dim DoubleDigits() As String = {"Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}
            Return tempText & DoubleDigits(num - 10)
        Else
            Dim TensPlace() As String = {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"}
            Dim t As Integer = num \ 10 'Tens place
            num -= t * 10
            If t > 1 Then
                tempText &= TensPlace(t - 2)
                If num > 0 Then
                    tempText &= " "
                End If
            End If
            If num > 0 Then
                tempText &= OneDigitText(num)
            End If
            Return tempText
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function OneDigitText(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    If num > 9 Or Num < 0 Then
        Return "Error"
    Else
        Dim SingleDigits() As String = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"}
        Return SingleDigits(num)
    End If
End Function
```

Since this is for school, you will probably want to adapt parts of my code to your own rather than copy the whole thing. (Teachers can usually tell when you get code off the internet, especially if you can't explain every line.) If you have any questions about it, send them to the email listed in my profile.

Comment: Thank you for such a big example. I will chew on this, and be sure to send an email if I have any questions!